# How to add an app to a group chat in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

The [What's New for MS Teams](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-s-new-in-microsoft-teams-d7092a6d-c896-424c-b362-a472d5f105de) on November 13, 2018

> **Apps on apps on apps**
>
> Why let channels have all the fun? Now your private group chats can
>   add dozens of apps as tabs to make working together even more
>   seamless. Manage project deadlines with Trello, readily access notes
>   with OneNote, track business analytics with PowerBI, and so much more.
>   Check out all the apps available by selecting the + at the top of any
>   group chat.

However, the `+` button does not exist in the group chat screen in the desktop application (1.2.00.17057) or the Office365 web interface.

How do I do this?

Comment: I have the same version as you. Have checked in desktop and web interface I can see the + button. Would be great if you can share screenshot of what you have on your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have explored further and found that this may be affecting on your case.

Assuming if you have admin access

1. Go to https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/Settings/ServicesAndAddIns
2. Click on Teams. Under the Apps. Make sure you have enabled the following settings to see the + icon
3. The checkbox "Allow External Apps" let you `When this setting is turned on, users can add external apps that are available to your organization`.

Here is the official link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/enable-features-office-365

Hope it helps

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tick the checkbox Allow external apps or sideloading of apps in Teams settings. You can go through the documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/enable-features-office-365